# Crontab: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: cron, jobs

I want to run a specific file every 5 minutes.

I have set up the crontab, but it just does not update.

I am using a BunsenLabs laptop running Debian 8.

Cron command:

```
5 * * * * /bin/bash /var/www/directory.com/public_html/cronfiletorun.php
```

Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction to get this running please?

I have tried numerous methods but cant seem to get anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run a php file. Change this `/bin/bash` to `php`:

```
*/5 * * * * php /var/www/directory.com/public_html/cronfiletorun.php
```

I am assuming, you got the file path right. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As written, that won't run it every five minutes, it'll run five minutes after every hour.  You need a list of times.  From the manual for crontab(5):

> Lists are allowed. A list is a set of numbers (or ranges) separated by commas. Examples: "1,2,5,9", "0-4,8-12".

In your case, it would be `0,5,10,15,...,50,55`.

Comment: Possibly you have a different cron program that doesn't grok lists?  Try Chukwuemeka Inya's answer which appears to have a different syntax for specifying every five minutes, and try seeing what the output from `man crontab` says.

Comment: Also, you didn't just copy and paste what I typed, I hope.  The elipsis are intended to state that you include every multiple of 5 from 0 to 55 inclusive in the comma separated list.

Comment: Updated now. But now it's not running the cron